# Iterate through instantiated objects of a class

Tags: python, class, object

Isit possible to loop through the objects of class person and extract the attributes?

so for e.g. from below code after looping the output would be for each object as such 
Object mike, name-Mike, age-20

```
class Person(object):
    def__init__(self,name,age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age


mike = Person('Mike',20)
john = Person('John',20)
jack = Person('Jack',20)
adam = Person('Adam',20)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Python classes don't automatically track all their instances.  You can use a class attribute to track them yourself if you need to:

```
class Person(object):
    people = []

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.people.append(self)
```

Even better would be to have a separate object that tracked people.  The Person.people attribute here is a single global value for the process, which can limit the usability and testability of the class.

Comment: That could potentially be a [weak reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html), so that instances *only* being tracked by the class can be released.

Comment: Hi thanks however prints the location of each object and not the name of object and its attributes, i don't know if this could be extracted by having the location or not?

Comment: You have to print the individual attributes, or define  a `__repr__` method in your class that prints then - check the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Answer (score 1):

To loop the attributes of a given instance, I think you're looking for the builtin function `vars`:

```
>>> mike = Person('Mike', 20)
>>> vars(mike)
{'age': 20, 'name': 'Mike'}
```

To loop through all instances of a given class is not possible, unless you add some code to maintain the list of instances yourself.

Comment: thanks for making me aware about this function, it can be quite useful in certain situations but does not serve my purpose for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

if my understanding is right, you are asking about looping the class person
then it can be done like this.

```
class person(object):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
for name,age in {'mike':20,'john':20,'jack':20}.iteritems():
    p = person(name,age)
    print ('I am %s my age is %d' %(p.name,p.age))
```

## answer

I am mike my age is 20
I am john my age is 20
I am jack my age is 20

Comment: thanks for your response. In this solution however you'd have to list the attributes of every object you've instantiated manually so its not directly looping through class.